# running a mapper and reducer program in hadoop-3.1.3

Tags: docker, hadoop

I am trying to run a hadoop container. What I did is I downloaded hadoop from
https://hadoop.apache.org/releases.html
I downloaded 3.1.3 file https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/hadoop/common/hadoop-3.1.3/hadoop-3.1.3-src.tar.gz the installation was successful. I see following

```
debian@osboxes:~$ docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
python              latest              eeadc22d21a9        2 weeks ago         933MB
hadoop-build-1001   latest              1d1a162a72a6        3 months ago        2.02GB
hadoop-build        latest              5c1480006f78        3 months ago        1.96GB
ubuntu              xenial              5f2bf26e3524        3 months ago        123MB
```

Now when I try to run an image

```
 docker run -it --user debian 1d1a162a72a6
```

I get error

```
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused "chdir to cwd (\"/root\") set in config.json failed: permission denied": unknown.
debian@osboxes:~$
```

I was not able to understand any thing as why these errors are coming and how to get rid of above error.
I somehow could login to container as root user and then inside that I did a `su debian` so I was able to login as debian,
Now I have programs mapper and reducer which I wanted to run in them. 
I did then

```
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install default-jdk wget -y
RUN apt-get install python3 -y
RUN wget
http://mirrors.estointernet.in/apache/hadoop/common/hadoop-2.10.0/hadoop-2.10.0.tar.gz
RUN tar -xzvf hadoop-2.10.0.tar.gz
ENV JAVA_HOME $(readlink -f /usr/bin/java | sed "s:bin/java::")
RUN mv hadoop-2.10.0 /usr/local/hadoop
ENV PATH /usr/local/hadoop/bin:$PATH
RUN rm -rf hadoop-2*
```

now I have installed hadoop-2.10.0 in hadoop 3 and then I executed my programmes.
I had to edit .bashrc of debian inside container.
I am wondering how could I run the mapper and reducer program in the hadoop-3.1.3 which I had build and compiled from sources or did I do any mistake here?

Is there a better way to use the hadoop-3.1.3 environment which took me hours to compile and install.

**update 1**

in the build script of hadoop sources file I downloaded there are following lines

```
docker build -t "hadoop-build-${USER_ID}" - <<UserSpecificDocker
FROM hadoop-build
RUN groupadd --non-unique -g ${GROUP_ID} ${USER_NAME}
RUN useradd -g ${GROUP_ID} -u ${USER_ID} -k /root -m ${USER_NAME}
RUN echo "${USER_NAME} ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL" > "/etc/sudoers.d/hadoop-build-${USER_ID}"
ENV HOME /home/${USER_NAME}

UserSpecificDocker

# By mapping the .m2 directory you can do an mvn install from
# within the container and use the result on your normal
# system.  And this also is a significant speedup in subsequent
# builds because the dependencies are downloaded only once.
docker run --rm=true -t -i \
  -v "${PWD}:/home/${USER_NAME}/hadoop${V_OPTS:-}" \
  -w "/home/${USER_NAME}/hadoop" \
  -v "${HOME}/.m2:/home/${USER_NAME}/.m2${V_OPTS:-}" \
  -u "${USER_NAME}" \
  "hadoop-build-${USER_ID}"
"start-build-env.sh"
```

so I think I am having development environment of hadoop.
However my problem lies in containers. 
When I do `docker ps -a` 
I see

```
19a4eff3b5e5        1d1a162a72a6        "/bin/bash"              3 hours ago         Exited (0) 3 hours ago                          assignment4
30933891f08c        eeadc22d21a9        "python3"                3 hours ago         Exited (0) 3 hours ago                          python
ccdab94fd32f        1d1a162a72a6        "/bin/bash"              9 hours ago         Exited (0) 5 hours ago                          confident_wu
ce462ecfc5f2        1d1a162a72a6        "/bin/bash -v /home/…"   9 hours ago         Exited (127) 9 hours ago                        stupefied_grothendieck
6123f134934c        1d1a162a72a6        "/bin/bash"              9 hours ago         Exited (1) 9 hours ago                          stupefied_taussig
0ed23a8112a4        1d1a162a72a6        "/bin/bash"              10 hours ago        Exited (0) 10 hours ago                         vigilant_bartik
c343731b7cde        1d1a162a72a6        "/bin/bash"              11 hours ago        Exited (0) 10 hours ago                         gallant_ardinghelli
2f95d3b4c1b8        1d1a162a72a6        "/bin/bash"              11 hours ago        Created                                         nice_hermann
5ebe9f18c744        1d1a162a72a6        "/bin/bash"              27 hours ago        Created                                         pensive_easley
c1b43edfafb9        1d1a162a72a6        "/bin/bash"              27 hours ago        Exited (1) 3 hours ago                          adoring_williams
42dea69d1d4e        1d1a162a72a6        "/bin/bash"              27 hours ago        Created                                         funny_austin
6f736902e650        1d1a162a72a6        "/bin/bash"              27 hours ago        Exited (1) 27 hours ago                         strange_ride
09306e5ec5d1        1d1a162a72a6        "--name=kaushik"         32 hours ago        Created                                         pensive_shtern
699fb2a23e1c        1d1a162a72a6        "--name=kaushik"         32 hours ago        Created                                         sharp_feistel
9f7b29ab512e        1d1a162a72a6        "--name=kaushik"         32 hours ago        Created                                         elastic_payne2
25bfc74fab3b        1d1a162a72a6        "/bin/bash"              33 hours ago        Exited (1) 31 hours ago                         festive_einstein
e658dd320297        1d1a162a72a6        "/bin/bash"              33 hours ago        Up 3 hours                                      objectiv:
```

I do not know how many containers were created and I made changes to enviornments inside containers. After a reboot I could not find any changes made to these containers. How can my containers survive a reboot?

Comment: Please just use existing Hadoop docker images and do not mix versions

Comment: You also don't need to run your code from a container. You just configure it from anywhere to use the YARN cluster address

Comment: I am not able to understand how to use existing image to run mapper and reducer code. I have the code but I am not clear how to do I have every thing on localhost.

Comment: Then learn without using containers. Hadoop was never designed or intended to run in Docker

Answer (score 0):

> I am not able to understand how to use existing image to run mapper and reducer code.

Run `docker exec` to enter into the container

Run `yarn jar` commands...

No different than any other way to submit jobs

Comment: I slightly added new information in question. Can you tell me how can I make my containers or some thing which I have done inside a container let survive a reboot for example I created mapper.py and reducer.py and edited .bashrc files how can I let that thing be using or save in container even after a reboot or I have exited the container. This is basically a learning environment where are trying to learn basics of hadoop by running hadoop in containers and mapper reducer programs. It is not a production environment.

Comment: It doesn't matter if it isn't production. Learn Hadoop without Docker or learn docker without Hadoop. Combining them will likely only confuse you

Comment: Plus, very very few people actually write mapreduce code anyway. Pyspark would be a better option to learn

Comment: I am doing a homework problem where I have to run hadoop inside containers and do check map reduce programs.I am not doing because I want to do it.

Comment: My mapreduce education didn't touch Docker at all. Mapreduce code already runs inside **YARN containers**

Comment: here is a link to pdf of assignment https://drive.google.com/file/d/16_V346v-ESvXbncdgytk-hcRTdMejHbN/view?usp=sharing I refer to question2 in the pdf on page 4 title Hadoop Assignment, I had downloaded source tar balls from apache website for hadoop packages and when every thing finished compiling that is what I get I am comfortable in using the compiled source code of hadoop which I did from scratch, I did that for a learning and I had been doing that from past 2-3 months some how could not proceed much I tried to proceed with this assignment in that compiled thing only. This  assignment was

Comment: Given to us 2 weeks before the deadline has gone so the questions which I am posting are not for people do my home work kind of thing it is that I am not able to understand what was to be done and there were some problem I compiled hadoop environment .From the make files now not sure how to proceed to use hadoop in that system. I could not do the assignment as they asked and I don't have any one to help me we get a lot of assignments  every week in different subjects , it is very tough to follow every thing after 9-5 PM class schedule and then discuss on forums etc.

Comment: There are students who could have helped but they did not they said me to do it by myself and fix what ever is the problem. i have an exam today so I will not be able to check this thread for one week.